# Comma before a conjunction that precedes an infinitive phrase?

Tags: phrases, commas, conjunctions, infinitives, clauses

I understand that a comma is used before "and" when the conjunction precedes an independent clause; however, I'm curious if the same rule applies when it precedes an infinitive phrase:

"It was my job to extract data necessary to determine the prevalences of rare mutations that could be lethal(,) and to ultimately calculate such statistics."

Thank you!

Comment: This is a matter of style and clarity.

Comment: I would use the comma, but I wouldn't use "such" in that sentence. Data isn't an example of statistics. I'd perhaps say, "calculate statistics thereof".

Having said that, I also would invert the sentence and simplify it to say, "It was my job to derive statistics from data determining the prevalence of rare and potentially lethal mutations"

Comment: @ChrisSubagio It was my intention for "such statistics" to refer to "prevalences," a type of epidemiological statistic. Sorry if that was unclear out of context.  Does that change your opinion?

Comment: It does, but I did not read that from the sentence as given. That sort of ambiguity is exactly why I'd shy away from using the referential "such" unless I was really stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You have a compound infinitive describing your job:  "to extract and to calculate."  You also have a predicate complement "lethal" in the relative clause "that could be lethal."  You have to decide whether leaving out the comma will momentarily mislead your reader into thinking that the complement might turn out to be compound, as in "that could be lethal and unfortunate."  That's what I take Robusto to mean by "clarity."

If both the comma and its absence leave you unsatisfied, you have to decide whether it might be better to rephrase entirely, perhaps "It was my job to calculate the statistics from the data I extracted, ...."  That's what I take Robusto to mean by "style."

Comment: +1: Right on both counts. I feel that the addition of *to* after *and* probably makes the clarity issue a moot point, though.